# Java practice OCAJP confusing answers

Tags: java

I'm doing some free practice exams on https://www.myexamcloud.com and I'm getting some weird answers here.

> 1. When the objects are equal by equals(Object) method then its hash codes also must be equal

I answered `false`, because there is possibility of that not being true, but it was wrong answer. Now I'm not sure what they are asking me here: if this is a good practice, if this is a must according to equals-hashCode contract or if there is simply no possibility with every code combination.

> 2. Which of the following sentences are TRUE about Java source files?
>
>    a. package statement must be the first line
>
>    b. comments can be placed before package statements

Those are the two correct answers (I checked `b` only), to me it just looks like a contradiction. If package statement must be the first line then how can comments before it be allowed?

> 3. Which of the following statements are TRUE?
>
>    a. Implicit casting is not permitted in all kinds of transformations

What do they mean by this, what transformations? To me transformation is a word that can mean basically anything (casting, cloning, mapping etc.) and it's not 
a special word in Java.

> 4. Which of the following statements are TRUE?
>
>    a. A valid override has identical argument types and order, identical return type, and is not less accessible than the original method
>
>    b. A valid override has identical argument types and order. Return type can be different

I checked `b`, but `a` is correct. How is `b` not correct if there is a possibility of overriding with covariant return type?

I understand that this site is not official, that's why I ask this question. Can I expect such questions on official exam? I noticed that those exams are trying to fool and bait me a lot, but here it simply seems wrong to me, like questions have not enough information/context to answer it.

Comment: Removed oracle tag (post is about Java)

Comment: Well, I meant that official exam is from oracle, not the oracle databases, sorry.

Comment: Better to post them in 4 questions

Comment: 1. You *can* violate the contract. But you must not. Else stuff won't work as expected. But you can do it, just like you said. I don't like those kind of questions. As long as you know how it works and understood everything, you shouldn't really care much for their interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

1- Most likely the question has referred to the <s>best practices</s> expected contract of implementing `equals`/`hashCode`. It's not prohibited by the compiler to make them return different results, though - but I've yet to see a valid use case for such behavior, and, as such, would question it any time I see it. Presumably the exam tries to enforce this <s>best practice</s> expected contract as a rule

2- What they most likely meant here is that the package statement must be the first **processed** line (as comments are ignored by the compiler) - i.e., you can't place import statements before the package statement, for example. So no contradiction here, just an unclear wording. And yes, you can expect the same lack of clarity in the exam, so be on a lookout.

3- Hard to make out what they meant without the context. Maybe include the other answer choices as well? Transformations can indeed refer to various actions in Java

4- The question here is not whether the presented choice is the only valid one. Answer `a` presents a narrower set than the possible valid overrides (as yes, the return type can be different, as long as it's co-variant); however, this wording also explicitly cuts off any invalid override implementations, while `b` does not (note the lack of the `not less accessible` clause). So `a` will always be correct, even though it doesn't cover all valid cases; `b`, on the other hand, covers valid as well as invalid cases, and thus can **possibly** be incorrect at times. Again, do expect such questions on the actual exam, where you will have to read **very carefully**

Comment: 2. "The package statement must be *on* the first processed line (not just *the* first processed line). The first processed line may contain other statements following the package statement.

Comment: 4. Well, to me `a` is not true at all. Imagine you have a list of methods and you have to determine whether they are `overrides` or not. If you apply all rules from answer `a` you will mark some `overrides` as `not-overrides`, while with `b` it's not gonna happen - you will have some methods left as `unclear`, but it's better than being wrong.

Comment: @Shadov But that's not what they're asking here. The semantics here is not "A valid override is exhaustively defined by the definition X", but rather "All overrides defined by a definition X are valid". The former semantics is false for either `a` or `b` (`a` is too narrow, while `b` is too wide), but the latter semantics is always true for `a`, but not for `b`. Again, not trying to argue with you here, as I agree the question is a bit of a "gotcha", just trying to explain the line of thinking that the exam seem to use, as it's different from yours

Answer (score 3):

> 1. When the objects are equal by equals(Object) method then its hash codes also must be equal

The answer is true. This is a general contract of an object when one trying to implement a `hashcode()` method. Taken from api doc: 
`If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.`

Try imagine on how `HashMap` handle collision when the equal method return true but the hashcode return different value for two objects.

> 2. Which of the following sentences are TRUE about Java source files?
>
>    - a. package statement must be the first line
>    - b. comments can be placed before package statements

Both are correct because the comments section are not a part of compilation unit. Taken from [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3)

> CompilationUnit:
>
> ```
> OrdinaryCompilationUnit
> ModularCompilationUnit
> ```
>
> OrdinaryCompilationUnit:
>
> ```
> [PackageDeclaration] {ImportDeclaration} {TypeDeclaration}
> ```
>
> ModularCompilationUnit:
>
> ```
> {ImportDeclaration} ModuleDeclaration
> ```

> 3. Which of the following statements are TRUE?
>      a. Implicit casting is not permitted in all kinds of transformations

This is kinda a bit vague. But, I would assume this is true. As, if it is permitted, then this expression should also run (it should not run though)

```
long a = 123L;
int b = a;
```

> 4. Which of the following statements are TRUE?
>      a. A valid override has identical argument types and order, identical return type, and is not less accessible than the original method
>      b. A valid override has identical argument types and order. Return type can be different

Though b make a valid choice. Option a is more specific than the other option. Thus, the b could also imply that, the overridden method, could be more accessible than the original method.

Through my experience taking the exam. The question should be very clear (means that, there should be no trick question involved). So, I guess you could try to take the mock exam from them. But, try to also use other mock exam. And also, read some other book.

Best of luck.

Comment: 1. I know about equals and hashcode, but it says `must` - what is must exactly (imagine you didn't know the api doc by heart)? To me `must` = if you don't then compilation error will happen.

Comment: Well, I don’t think there is a way to produce a reliable way to create a compilation error to check whether the hash code and equal conform the contract because there are many ways to check the end user code. And, it simply how other api interact with each other that you need to aware of.( regardless what language you’re using)